# "Ecma Error: TypeError: Cannot find default value for object" when running on remote Worklight server

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-adapters

In Worklight, after using the "build setting and deploy target" option and building all environments I have proceeded to deploy the WAR file and wlapp files on worklight console of the remote server.

now when i try to run my app from the worklight console i get lots of 404 errors
"NetworkError: 404 Not Found:

[image]

and when i run my http adapter I get the below error:

> ```
> response [/SocialRatingV2/apps/services/api/SocialRatingV2/desktopbrowser/query]
> ```
>
> success: /*-secure-
>       {"isSuccessful":false,"WL-Authentication-Success":{"wl_anonymousUserRealm":{"userId":"24fbe6d3-40f3-4535-993a-4f3928cbc0e1","attributes":{},"isUserAuthenticated":1,"displayName":"24fbe6d3-40f3-4535-993a-4f3928cbc0e1"},"wl_antiXSRFRealm":{"userId":"fsu8rka0ogkvr6ia3egm9j3rqn","attributes":{},"isUserAuthenticated":1,"displayName":"fsu8rka0ogkvr6ia3egm9j3rqn"}},"warnings":[],"errors":["Ecma
>   Error: TypeError: Cannot find default value for object.
>   (bluepagesAPI-impl.js#41)"],"info":[]}*/

Comment: What is in line #41 in your bluepagesAPI-impl.js adpater file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After talking privately with the user, removing the line at #41 magically made it work again.

Not particularly helpful answer, but that's the best that can be written w/out the code from the application.

Comment: The issue was in the line WL.Logger.info("++++++++++++++++++LOG++++++++++++++++"+resultbluepage);

Comment: I was trying to print the result without stringifying it .... When i commented this line .... the error vanished :)